# Embed google maps as directive / factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm struggling with a design issue in AngularJS. I'm trying to achieve a sort of 2-way binding between the map and my forms and actions specified on the left part. Clicking on the map should add a marker on the map itself + the place should appear on the left. Clicking on a "Add place" button on the left should do the same thing.

However, when switching to another part of the site, for example routes, different things should happen when receiving events of the map, or clicking it.

[image: Illustration of the wobsite]

The options I've tried:

- Parent container has a directive attached, which setups google maps. Has two child divs, one with ui-view, so it can change based on routes. The other which will contain the map. The problem here is that I'll always need a directive to communicate with the map, as I need to require the parent container. Seems not ideal
- Implemented the map as a factory.It setups the map & exposes functions with which you can manipulate the map. Since there is no scope, every triggered event needs a $rootScope.$apply(). The service can emit events that google maps broadcasts with $rootScope, so that controllers or directives can listen to it. Still, not sure how to properly implements scenarios like "when hovering over Place A item, show a marker on the map", I'm binding the map logic to the directive this way..

Are there other alternatives or tricks in angularjs that would make this eas(y/ier) to implement?

Comment: all this is pretty simple by using  https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Comment: Can I switch pages/controllers with that directive without causing the map to reload? <div> <div ui-view ng-controller="A"></div> <google-maps></div>. A won't be able to influence the directive here no?

Comment: can use service for map data and bind all controller map related data to service

Comment: mm, can't help to find it strange to use directives to manipulate google maps though. You have to add html to add markers and the likes, while it seems to make more sense to do this programmatically, or is that just me?

Comment: makes it very easy since events bound to map will already be in agular scope

Comment: Did you decide on an approach for this? I am in a similar situation

Comment: I've decided to go for the service, I found it made more sense to use it since I was manipulating the map from various controllers. The issue however is that your service will persist, so any markers you placed on one page, will stay on another etc.